# Error when debugging of flutter in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Connecting to VM Service at `ws://127.0.0.1:52373/PSOLWnX5IdE=/ws"` error is come in debugging of flutter code in VScode, please tell me how to fix it

[image]

Comment: This is not a error. Flutter connects with VM service for starting execution.

Comment: it is showing continuously many hours

Comment: so it means your code is not running it's only stuck at connection. you can try some fixes. run commands on terminal, `flutter upgrade` ("it will upgrade flutter to latest version"). `flutter clean` and also run `flutter doctor` to check is there any issue

Answer (score 0):

Close your current project and run any different and see if it runs. In my case I was getting the same error, so I open a new project and guess what it ran successfully. So I removed my project that was not working and cloned it again. There was no error this time.